# Printing out service object error

Tags: python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on an exercise which requires that I output the **dimensions** and **resolution** of map data to the command-line output.

I am calling the `static_map` service from python code but when I try printing the required output I get **Service has no attribute info** type messages. The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from nav_msgs.srv import GetMap

def print_map_data(req):
    print "Returning [%s]"%(req.info.resolution)

def read_map_service():
    rospy.init_node('my_map_service_reader')
    s = rospy.Service('/static_map', GetMap, print_map_data)
    print "Ready to print ...."
    rospy.loginfo("Ready to print ....")
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_map_service()
```

I have confirmed the structure of the service object by running `rossrv show nav_msgs/GetMap` and getting the following:

```
---
nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid map
  std_msgs/Header header
    uint32 seq
    time stamp
    string frame_id
  nav_msgs/MapMetaData info
    time map_load_time
    float32 resolution
    uint32 width
    uint32 height
    geometry_msgs/Pose origin
      geometry_msgs/Point position
        float64 x
        float64 y
        float64 z
      geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
        float64 x
        float64 y
        float64 z
        float64 w
  int8[] data
```

I would appreciate help in understanding what I'm doing wrong or missing here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368697/printing-out-service-object-error/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> def print_map_data(req):
> ```

```
    print "Returning [%s]"%(req.info.resolution)
```

The first (and only) field at the top-level of the [nav_msgs/GetMap](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetMap.html) service is `map`:

```
# Get the map as a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid
---
nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid map
```

the `map` field then contains the `header`, `info` and the `data` fields.

So you'd need to change your callback to:

```
def print_map_data(req):
    print "Returning [%s]"%(req.map.info.resolution)
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0